# Backbone.js TypeError: a.$ is undefined Error

Tags: backbone.js

I am newbie in backbone.js. I was trying to execute below code of backbone.js but getting an error like **"TypeError: a.$ is undefined"** . I have included below js files in order to run below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="backbone-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var Usermodel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/user',
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }
});
var user = new Usermodel();
// Notice that we haven't set an `id`
var userDetails = {
    name: 'Thomas',
    email: 'thomasalwyndavis@gmail.com'
};

user.save(userDetails, {
    success: function (user) {
        alert(user.toJSON());
    }
});
```

Please let me know why I am getting above error. What is wrong with above code?

Thanks, Jimit

Comment: load jquery file dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please download jquery and add below tag before backbone tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi CodeJack, Can you tell me which are dependencies of backbone.js?

Comment: Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( >= 1.4.3). For RESTful persistence, history support via Backbone.Router and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include json2.js, and either jQuery ( >= 1.7.0) or Zepto.